# Setting type of the nodes in a bipartite weighted graph

Tags: r

I have a dataset of three columns called "rede" being rede$PORT rede$COUNTRY  and rede$WEIGHT the columns of the dataset.

I try to create a bipartite graph with the two firs columns as vertex and the third column as the Weight of the edge between them.

So I execute

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(rede)
E(g)$weight <- rede$WEIGHT
```

According to the bipartite documentation, if the graph is bipartite, g$type should be TRUE for nodes in rede$PORT AND false for
nodes in rede$COUNTRY, but initially  g$type is NULL.

To try to solve it, I set all the `$type` nodes to TRUE

```
V(g)$type <- FALSE
```

Now the graph is bipartite, but all the nodes belong to group 2.

To set the group 1 nodes to False I tried

```
V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% rede[,2]
```

I try to set `V(g)$type` to TRUE for those nodes belonging to category COUNTRY: second column of the dataset, but It's not working, and of course if I plot the graph as bipartite:

```
plot(g, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=7, layout=layout.bipartite)
```

I get a Flat plot.

Any help about how to set V(g)$type to True if the name of the Node is in rede[,2] and then get a true bipartite graph will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answwer, just in case someone may need it...
V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type